# Вылазит ошибка при вычислении случайного числа

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сгенерировать случайное число от первого до второго числа, которые вводит пользователь. Но вылезает ошибка.
код:

```
elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("g"):
    print('Рандомайзер запущен.')
    print('Чтобы произвести случайное число - введите 0 в строку первого и второго чисел.')
    print('Чтобы произвести случайное число от одной цифры до другой - введите их в строку для первого и второго чисел.')
    the_first_random_number = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
    the_second_random_number = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
    user_numbers = random.randint(the_first_random_number, the_second_random_number)
    print(user_numbers)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Programs\test.py", line 56, in <module>
    user_numbers = random.randint(the_first_random_number, the_second_random_number)
  File "C:\питон\lib\random.py", line 338, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\питон\lib\random.py", line 316, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (8, 4, -4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно `empty range`.

```
randrange(<START>,<STOP>,<STEP>)
```

Вы пытаетесь 8 взять за старт, а надо за стоп. И еще шаг не может быть отрицательным.

На всякий случай:
`START < STOP && STEP > 0`

Comment: Шаг таки может быть отрицательным (правда, в randint опции шага всё равно нету)

Comment: Так это `randrange`. Вообще я с ним не очень работал и насчет шага действительно могу ошибаться)

Comment: А, я на ошибку смотрю, а не на код... Поняв

Answer (score 0):

Ну ты просто проверяй нули:

```
elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("g"):
    print('Рандомайзер запущен.')
    print('Чтобы произвести случайное число - введите 0 в строку первого и второго чисел.')
    print('Чтобы произвести случайное число от одной цифры до другой - введите их в строку для первого и второго чисел.')
    the_first_random_number = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
    the_second_random_number = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
    if the_first_random_number == the_second_random_number == 0:
         user_number = random.randint(0, 2 ** 16)
    else:
         user_numbers = random.randint(the_first_random_number, the_second_random_number)
    print(user_numbers)
```

P.S. И имена переменных не пиши такие огромные. Вполне бы подошли в стиле: `rand_num_1`, `rand_num_2`.